# Getting React Developer Tools to Work with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, developer-tools

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) to expose React as global in Webpack. The `Expose` module is installed & I added the module loader in config webpack.config.js file. However, its not working & React Developer Tools are still not accessible.

Here is my webpack.config.js file, the first loader is expose-react:

```
var path = require ('path'),
    webpack = require ('webpack'),
    htmlWebpackPlugin = require ('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
    app : path.join (__dirname, 'app'),
    build : path.join (__dirname, 'build')
};

module.exports = {
    entry : {
        main : PATHS.app + '/Main.jsx'
    },
    output : {
        path : PATHS.build,
        filename : 'dressAphrodite.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : require.resolve ('react'),
                loader : 'expose?React'
            },
            {
                test : /\.css$/,
                loaders : ['style', 'css'],
                include : PATHS.app
            },
            {
                test : /\.js?$/,
                loader : 'babel-loader',
                include : PATHS.app
            },
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loader : 'babel-loader',
                include : PATHS.app
            }
        ]
    },
    debug : true,
    devtool : 'source-map',
    devServer : {
        contentBase : './app',
        progress : true,
        stats : 'errors-only',
    },
    plugins : [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin ({
            title : 'Dress',
            hash : true
        })
    ]
};
```

And just for info for which dependencies are installed, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./main.jsx",
  "dependencies": {
    "i": "^0.3.3",
    "npm": "^3.5.2",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And here is the .babelrc file content :

```
{
  'presets' : [
    'es2015',
    'react'
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There is actually a solution for this, you have to start webpack with --inline option on [more here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#inlined-mode), so the server will be located in localhost:8080 instead of localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server, and hot reloading will still work and you'll be able to see your react dev tools :D

Comment: Thank you!!! This needs more upvotes. Solved my problem and I almost didn't see it because it was buried so low.

Comment: plain and simple. Just access `localhost:8080' without the '/webpack-dev-server' part. It works just fine here without any additional configs on webpack

Comment: Accessing without `/webpack-dev-server` means the page will not automatically reload when you change your source code.  Hot Module Replacement (HMR) will also not work.  Lastly, the "inline" option is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. However, [the devtools FAQ](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) currently states "Currently iframes and Chrome apps/extensions are not inspectable", and webpack runs in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. But desperately wanted this feature.

Answer (score 4):

Since React 0.12 you don't need to expose React as global anymore.

**Important:** if you are opening directly your html file without using a server, in other words, if you are using *file://* URLs you need to allow the extension to access these kind of URLs: To do that go to settings>extensions, look for React Developer Tools and check the box saying "Allow access to file URLs".

When bundling React files written with jsx syntax you need to transform the file to pure javascript. To do that you need to use babel-preset-react which you already have installed but you are not using in your webpack.config.js.

You also don't need to import webpack in your webpack.config.js and the *test* property in the objects inside the *loaders* array is a regular expression, so /.jsx?$/ is enough to match js or jsx files.

Here is a working example of how to output a bundle of your React files (I removed the html-webpack-plugin so you need to write your own page)

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require ('path');

var PATHS = {
    app : path.join (__dirname, 'app'),
    build : path.join (__dirname, 'build')
};

module.exports = {
    entry : {
        main : PATHS.app + '/main.js'
    },
    output : {
        path : PATHS.build,
        filename : 'bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?$/,
                loader : 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**main.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Component = require('./component.js');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```

**component.js**

```
var React = require('react');

var Test = React.createClass({
  diplayName: "Test",

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>Test</div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = Test;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>

    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer along with corrections. The reason I removed the query from Webpack file is because I have the preset defined in '.babelrc' file. I am updating the above question with .babelrc file. 
---- It seems that html-webpack-plugin may have something to do with it. Yes, it will start running if I load the React manually.

Comment: I kept the webpack-html-plugin and made the above suggestions & react dev tools are still not accessible. I should also mention that my build is working fine, I am able to code React and see the components output on live server.

Comment: I forgot something about file URLs that are probably your problem. I updated my question with this last thing.

Comment: Can you tell me the version of your React Dev Tools? And the output of this in the chrome console: `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__`

Comment: Thanks, React Dev Tools for Chrome is version 0.14.6.1 & for Firefox is version 0.14.6. Here is the output of `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` : `_listeners: Object
_relayInternals: (...)
get _relayInternals: get()
set _relayInternals: set(relayInternals)
_renderers: Object
emit: emit(evt, data)
helpers: Object
inject: inject(renderer)
nativeMap: Map()
nativeObjectCreate: create()
nativeSet: Set()
nativeWeakMap: WeakMap()
off: off(evt, fn)
on: on(evt, fn)
sub: sub(evt, fn)
__proto__: Object`

Comment: I have the same version and I tested with htmlWebpackPlugin and webpack dev server and everything works fine. The only thing I can think about is some conflict with other extension. There is any output in your React Dev Tools background page? (to access the background page you need to enable the developer mode flag in your chrome extensions page)

Comment: Thanks. However, React doesnt recognise in either Chrome & Firefox so I wonder. Console reports no errors except in Firefox Dev Version where it states: The connection to ws://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/829/t0n1kw15/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: Did you sort this out? Having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding file:// URLs